# Botframework on Microsoft-Teams: Issue about sending reply message to user

Tags: rest, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have developed a bot within Botframework and add the channel Microsoft Teams.

When user writes 'hi' in MS-Teams to the chatbot, my webhook receives the following message:

```
{
  "text": "hi",
  "textFormat": "plain",
  "type": "message",
  "timestamp": "2017-05-18T10:05:07.742Z",
  "id": "1495101906391",
  "channelId": "msteams",
  "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea-client-ss.msg/",
  "from": {
    "id": "29:1hyY0WDlv1ehVaSqIA-anqB9CMHoukm59yNjxcVxjTnb5s2B1_HtUI6GFmS1vC6w2XufYPX7L03xlY1qEEQtT2w",
    "name": "xxx"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "a:1ivnXQ6qsiT1hLo26tk4vL1vgUcanbkRm3mMsDj48HkQSKFwr87HCKUFvFoSqjMdGICUBYzds5MR1_kIBCJRY0GZyZ9fa3Yd3MXmlHUhLVA7XaXezOO5u7CaLTNghSiEM"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "28:4faa7ac7-bb35-4737-b49a-e21bbc3fb65d",
    "name": "xxx"
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "locale": "it-IT",
      "country": "IT",
      "platform": "Mac",
      "type": "clientInfo"
    }
  ],
  "channelData": {
    "tenant": {
      "id": "5cf8dc9b-6f57-4eff-a404-5518dc1826d6"
    }
  }
}
```

In order to reply to user question, i'm using the following endpoint:
https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea-client-ss.msg/v3/conversations/29:1hyY0WDlv1ehVaSqIA-anqB9CMHoukm59yNjxcVxjTnb5s2B1_HtUI6GFmS1vC6w2XufYPX7L03xlY1qEEQtT2w/activities/

with body:

```
{
  "action": "message",
  "channelData": {
    "tenant": {
      "id": "5cf8dc9b-6f57-4eff-a404-5518dc1826d6"
    }
  },
  "channelId": "msteams",
  "conversation": {
    "id": "a:1ivnXQ6qsiT1hLo26tk4vL1vgUcanbkRm3mMsDj48HkQSKFwr87HCKUFvFoSqjMdGICUBYzds5MR1_kIBCJRY0GZyZ9fa3Yd3MXmlHUhLVA7XaXezOO5u7CaLTNghSiEM"
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "locale": "it-IT",
      "country": "IT",
      "platform": "Mac",
      "type": "clientInfo"
    }
  ],
  "from": {
    "id": "28:4faa7ac7-bb35-4737-b49a-e21bbc3fb65d",
    "name": "XXX"
  },
  "id": "14950405460679",
  "replyToId": "1495040546067",
  "inputHint": "ignoringInput",
  "locale": "it-IT",
  "localTimestamp": "2017-05-17T17:02:25.716Z",
  "recipient": {
    "id": "29:1hyY0WDlv1ehVaSqIA-anqB9CMHoukm59yNjxcVxjTnb5s2B1_HtUI6GFmS1vC6w2XufYPX7L03xlY1qEEQtT2w",
    "name": "XXX"
  },
  "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea-client-ss.msg/",
  "text": "hi Antonio",
  "textFormat": "markdown",
  "type": "message",
  "timestamp": "2017-05-19T17:02:25.716Z"
}
```

I receive a 400 error with the following body

```
 {   
     "error": {
     "code": "ServiceError",
     "message": "Unsupported conversation type"   
     } 
 }
```

What is wrong about reply message? Are the endpoint and body correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `serviceUrl` endpoint is not meant to be POSTed to directly. The Bot Framework SDKs (and the underlying REST APIs) do that for you. The only endpoint you should be posting to is the "Messaging endpoint" specified for your bot in the Bot Framework portal - usually in the form `https://<your-bot-endpoint>/api/messages`.

Without seeing more of your code I can't be more specific, and I've never tried posting to the `serviceUrl` directly to see what happens, but what you observed isn't inconsistent with what I'd expect.

Here's a sample message **to** a bot:

```
{
    "text": "hello",
    "textFormat": "plain",
    "type": "message",
    "timestamp": "2017-05-19T19:34:57.1Z",
    "id": "1495222496101",
    "channelId": "msteams",
    "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer-client-ss.msg/",
    "from": {
        "id": "29:1b-XXgcDBMdLhH_MyEbE8u4C6re5IXsyM4diL4_6RBnOG-TCUm-YPsBGMq_cltQkc_paI8g5gsIVT6AgWFZigs5E49-i0F0OxpODhGY-IX08",
        "name": "Bill Bliss"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "id": "a:1X7RpEdoNRlujstg0zjaq_ouNBRrfN_brwVTHRzIdSEhAwS0XPa8uMlGl1Vrw4tOqIVLwN6WzWK1WyooWrPyVpsEcciyOJRI1snA_RMvUkejB39HCAZPtoJLUpgogTm_d"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "28:71d82610-942e-4115-b6a7-2ac1992ecb23",
        "name": "Build Bot  DEV "
    },
    "entities": [
        {
            "locale": "en-US",
            "country": "US",
            "platform": "Windows",
            "type": "clientInfo"
        }
    ],
    "channelData": {
        "tenant": {
            "id": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47"
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the reply **from** the bot:

```
{
    text: 'hello',
    textFormat: 'plain',
    type: 'message',
    timestamp: '2017-05-19T20: 00: 33.764Z',
    entities: [{
        locale: 'en-US',
        country: 'US',
        platform: 'Windows',
        type: 'clientInfo'
    }],
    sourceEvent: {
        tenant: {
            id: '72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47'
        }
    },
    attachments: [],
    address: {
        id: '1495224034790',
        channelId: 'msteams',
        user: {
            id: '29: 1b-XXgcDBMdLhH_MyEbE8u4C6re5IXsyM4diL4_6RBnOG-TCUm-YPsBGMq_cltQkc_paI8g5gsIVT6AgWFZigs5E49-i0F0OxpODhGY-IX08',
            name: 'BillBliss'
        },
        conversation: {
            id: 'a: 1X7RpEdoNRlujstg0zjaq_ouNBRrfN_brwVTHRzIdSEhAwS0XPa8uMlGl1Vrw4tOqIVLwN6WzWK1WyooWrPyVpsEcciyOJRI1snA_RMvUkejB39HCAZPtoJLUpgogTm_d'
        },
        bot: {
            id: '28: 71d82610-942e-4115-b6a7-2ac1992ecb23',
            name: 'BuildBotDEV'
        },
        serviceUrl: 'https: //smba.trafficmanager.net/amer-client-ss.msg/'
    },
    source: 'msteams',
    agent: 'botbuilder',
    user: {
        id: '29: 1b-XXgcDBMdLhH_MyEbE8u4C6re5IXsyM4diL4_6RBnOG-TCUm-YPsBGMq_cltQkc_paI8g5gsIVT6AgWFZigs5E49-i0F0OxpODhGY-IX08',
        name: 'BillBliss'
    }
}
```

Comment: If a bot wants to communicate with MS-Teams (i.e. if a bot wants to send a message to user via MS-Teams channel), which REST endpoint should be used? Could you also provide me a sample body? Thanks in advance

Comment: The same endpoint is used for all Bot Framework channels - the Messaging endpoint specified in the portal. The `channelId` field in the message indicates what channel the message arrived on.

I've updated my answer with a sample message **to** a bot and a reply **from** that bot.

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint URL should have the conversation ID, not the user ID. The `29:..` is the user ID.
Try sending the same payload with the conversation ID, which is located under: `"conversation": {"id": ".."}`

So in your case the URL should be:
`https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea-client-ss.msg/v3/conversations/a:1ivnXQ6qsiT1hLo26tk4vL1vgUcanbkRm3mMsDj48HkQSKFwr87HCKUFvFoSqjMdGICUBYzds5MR1_kIBCJRY0GZyZ9fa3Yd3MXmlHUhLVA7XaXezOO5u7CaLTNghSiEM/activities/`